# AppcompatImageView don't show VectorDrawable when I use ImageViewFilter with MotionLayout at previous screen

Tags: android

I have 2 screens (Splash and Home fragment). I use same icon (VectorDrawable Image) in both screen.

In SplashFragment, I use ImageFilterView in MotionLayout to show that icon. (for changing "crossfade" attributes)

[fragment_splash.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7hbk.png)

[splash_scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INr1G.png)

In HomeFragment, I use AppCompatImageView to show that icon again.

But in HomeFragment, ImageView don't show that icon (still have bound of view on screen).

[HomeFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtYBX.png)

I don't know why VectorDrawable not loaded when I use ImageFilterView at previous screen.

(preference sample project https://github.com/NXAN2901/ImageFilterView-Problem)

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem is fixed at ConstraintLayout version [2.1.0-beta02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout#constraintlayout-2.1.0-beta02)

Thanks for read it